# It is possible to develop Android 3.x applications with Netbeans?

Tags: android, netbeans

It is possible to develop Android 3.x applications with Netbeans? Would like to hear experience from users which are already developing programs with Netbeans and Android 3.x

Thanks

Comment: Dev questions are off-topic here :P

Comment: This should be moved to StackOverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For sure, just follow this tutorials:

- [How to setup Netbeans for Android development](http://gerry.ws/2009/01/1074/how-to-setup-netbeans-for-android-development.html)
- [Intro Android Dev - Netbeans Wiki](http://wiki.netbeans.org/IntroAndroidDevNetBeans)

Comment: The first link seems to be broken (http://gerry.ws/2009/01/1074/how-to-setup-netbeans-for-android-development.html)

Answer (score 2):

More up-to-date introduction is at http://www.nbandroid.org/p/installation.html

-Radim